# Does having Smallholder and Acreage when Sowing yield extra grain?

Tags: agricola

If I have the smallholder, and I sow I should get extra to place one extrs grain when I do so as long as I have two or fewer fields.

Acreage does not count as a field when scoring points, but I can sow grain on it.

If I sow grains on Acreage while I have two or fewer fields, do I get to place extra grain when Sowing on the fields and on the Acreage?

Answer (score 3):

Acreage counts as two fields for Smallholder, so you will not get extra sowing unless it is your only field.

[Source](https://alavigne.net/Gaming/Agricola/agricola-comp-v9.0.html#K286):

> Acreage, Bean Field, Lettuce Patch and Turnip Field count towards the indicated maximum of 2 fields, and you receive extra grain or vegetables on them because of the Smallholder. *The Acreage counts as two fields.*

It is worth noting that this is an "unofficial compendium", so it is not as definitive as an actual rulebook. But it has been compiled based on rulings from the designer, as well as discussions in the rules forums at boardgamegeek.com.